# Searching String Array item in a nested HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, arrays

I have a nested HashMap (`outer_map`), which has another HashMap inside of it as a value (`inner_map`), such implemented as

```
Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> outer_map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
Map<String, String> inner_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

The figure below illustrates the whole structures of the maps:
[image]
To make the long story short, I need to compare and search values inside the `outer_map`'s vlaue (`inner_map`) by ***String Array*** items, and then produce another ***String Array*** to add matched items.

> If the ***String Array*** has there elements which are the same as one of the **`inner_map`**'s random (for example; **`value2`**, **`value1`**, and **`value7`**) values, how can I search and compare these items to add to another ***String Array***?

The latest code snippet I tried and I couldn't succeed:

```
if( !( theStringArray.equals("") ) )
{
    while( outer_map.keySet().iterator().hasNext() )
    {
       for( int i=0; i <= theStringArray.length; i++) 
       {
           // outer_map keys are order as 1,2,3,..,8
           theStringArray[i] = outer_map.get(String.valueOf(i+1)).get("key1");
           ...
       }
    }
}
```

**`EDIT`**: Map generating function

```
private void parse(String in) throws IOException
{
    reader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(in));
    ...
    int nodeCounter = 1;
    while(reader.hasNext())
    {    
        ...
            String nameAsKey1 = "blabla"; // value1
            inner_map.put("name", nameAsKey1);

            String surnameAsKey2 = "blabla"; // value2
            inner_map.put("surname", surnameAsKey2);
             ...

        outer_map.put(String.valueOf(nodeCounter), (HashMap<String, String>) inner_map);
        inner_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        nodeCounter++;
    }   
}
```

**`EDIT`**: I don't know how I can explain the issue more clearly, but may be this will help to understand about it: Map structure

[image]

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'inside' the outer_map ? As a key ? As a key of one of the inner maps inside it ? As a value inside one of the inner maps ?

Comment: Maps in java have a Method entrySet that returns the set of all entries in a map ... Check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet() .... You can do a foreach loop and loop over all the entries ... Or a nested loop, depending on how you want to search

Comment: Actually, there is one `outer_map` which has 8 same `inner_map`s except their keys.

Comment: what does "key1" mean,and your search criterion ? I don't think this  is a hard question ,but you have to make yourself clear of what you want to do.

Comment: As I edited in the code snippet, the `outer_map` has 8 key-value pairs such as; `[ 1=inner_map1, 2=inner_map2,..,8=inner_map8]`. And in one of each `inner_map` structure, I have `[name=blabla, surname=blala,...]`. I also added the map generating function in the question, sorry for the insignificant explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have an array of String and a Map of map. Now you want to search the value fields of inner map against the array of String and if make a new string array with matching values.

If that is the case the below program will help you..

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

public class InnerMapSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, HashMap<String, String>> outer_map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>();
        Map<String, String> inner_map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String[] searchParams = {"blabla1", "blabla3", "blabla20"};

        //Populating the map
        int reader = 1;
        while (reader < 10) {
            String nameAsKey1 = "blabla" + reader; // value1
            inner_map.put("name", nameAsKey1);

            String surnameAsKey2 = "blabla" + reader; // value2
            inner_map.put("surname", surnameAsKey2);

            outer_map.put(String.valueOf(reader), (HashMap<String, String>) inner_map);
            inner_map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            reader++;
        }

        //Searching
        Set<String> searchResults = new HashSet<String>(); // Using set to avoid duplicate

        // Iterate over the outer map
        for(String key : outer_map.keySet()){
            // Iterate through each inner_map value of outer map
            for(Entry<String, String> innerEntry : outer_map.get(key).entrySet()){
                // Iterate through the list of search params and see if its present in inner_hashmap
                for(String searchParam : searchParams){
                    if(searchParam.equals(innerEntry.getValue())){
                        // The search parameter is in inner map so adding to result.
                        searchResults.add(searchParam);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Converting the list to an array.
        String[] searchResultsArray = searchResults.toArray(new String[searchResults.size()]);
    }

}
```

Comment: That was what I've looking for `(Searching)`. Now I am able to produce another array to send to another class. Thank you, sir. Great and simple programming.